# $\{id_V,T,T^2,...,T^d\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimentional vector space over a field $F$, and $T:V\to V$ diagonalizable, where $c_1,...,c_r$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$.

Prove that

a) $p(t)=(t-c_1)\cdot ...\cdot (t-c_r)$ is the minimum polynomial of $T$.

b) If $A=\{id_V,T,T^2,...,T^d\}$ is linearly independent, then $d<r$.

I alredy prove that a) is true. But now I can't find a relation between the set $A$ and that $T$ is diagonalizable or something.

Any hint to solve b)?

By the way, I suppose that $A$ is linearly independent in the vector space of all linear transformations $V\to V$, am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p(t)$ is the minimal polynomial, by definition $p(T) = 0$. Since $\deg p = r$, this shows that $T^r$ is a linear combination of $1,\ldots,T^{r-1}$. You take it from here.